# Doctrine2 SoftDeleteable EventListener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How to create a EventListener to SoftDeleteableListener on doctrine 2 Event "postSoftDelete" to Loggable the changes in log entity with Doctrine Extensions?

Regards.

Comment: Most certainly because your question desn't really follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you have all [here](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions) : SoftDeletable + Loggable on delete

Best,